# Angularjs Datatables Columnfilter

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, filter, datatable

I use angularjs with [angular-datatables](https://github.com/l-lin/angular-datatables) and the [Columnfilter](https://code.google.com/p/jquery-datatables-column-filter/) plugin.
Initial Setup is working fine:

HTML:

```
<table datatable="" dt-options="data.dtOptions" dt-columns="data.dtColumns" class="table-1">
    <tfoot style="display: table-header-group">
        <tr>
            <th>id</th>
            <th>name</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

Controller for the Site:

```
var siteController = app.controller("siteController", function($scope, $route, $http, $location, $compile, DTOptionsBuilder, DTColumnBuilder) {
$scope.data = this;
$scope.data.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.fromSource('demodata.json')
.withDOM('<"top">rt<"bottom"ipl><"clear">')
.withColumnFilter({
        aoColumns: [
            null,
            {
                type: 'select',
                bRegex: false,
                values: ['Yoda', 'Titi', 'Kyle', 'Bar', 'Whateveryournameis']
            }
        ]
});
$scope.data.dtColumns = [
    DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('id').withTitle('id'),
    DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('name').withTitle('name')
];
```

});

Now there is an example to autofill the select-dropdown with table Data:

```
[...]
.withColumnFilter({
    aoColumns: [
        null,
        {
            type: 'select',
            bRegex: false,
            values: function(aoData, oSettings){
                var keys = new Array();
                var values = new Array()
                for(i=0; i<aoData.length; i++){
                    var item = aoData[i]._aData[3];
                    if(keys[item]==null){
                        keys[item] = true;
                        //values.push(item);
                        values.push({ value: item, label: 'The ' + item});
                    }
                }
                return values;
            }
        }
    ]
});
[...]
```

The site with the given example:
https://jquery-datatables-column-filter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ajaxSource.html

The example is not working. Does someone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I am also facing the same issue.

Comment: Page not found.